# Missing "[" at start of message send expression

Tags: objective-c

I don't see what is wrong with this code as line 4 is getting the "Missing "[" at start of message or expression" and line 6 is getting the error "Expected "].

```
- (void) subtractTime;
{
     seconds--;
     timerLabel.text[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i", seconds]

     if (seconds -- 0)
     {
           [timer invalidate];
     }
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong and this is really frustrating.

Comment: This question should be closed now that it has been answered because it is predicated on syntax errors that are unlikely to be reproduced in the same combination by anyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax issues in your code.

I added:

1. An equals sign after timerLabel.text, because you're setting the text.
2. A semicolon after the same line (it's the end of that statement).
3. A double equals sign for `seconds == 0` to compare if `seconds` equals `0`, otherwise the syntax is invalid.

Updated code:

```
- (void) subtractTime;
{
     seconds--;
     timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i", seconds];

     if (seconds == 0)
     {
           [timer invalidate];
     }
}
```

Important note:

1. Where is the `seconds` variable declared? Make sure this variable is properly managed or else it will always equal 0!

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked completely. seconds is called in another method called setupGame and has a value of 30 but it is declared in the .h file as a NSInteger so I hope all is well. Thankyou so much !

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. In your case, I would use `self.seconds` just to make your code easier to follow (though perhaps this is just my personal opinion and not a best practice). Anyway, don't forget to accept the answer, it helps our reps!

Comment: Sorry for not accepting straight away as I'm a very new member. I just clicked the tick and it turned green...is this it?

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot and welcome to the StackOverflow community!